# Half round half square parentheses

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Given a real random variable `X`, to express the probability

```
\Pr[X = a]/2 + \Pr[X \in (a,b)] + \Pr[X = b]/2
```

It could be convenient to just write

```
\Pr[X \in \{a,b\}]
```

where `\{` and `\}` are special parentheses symbols. I imagine these graphically as half-round (top part) half-square (bottom part) parentheses.

In my use case this kind of probabilities are ubiquitous, and a short notation (as suggested) is important. Also, I would like the notation to support a mixed-type interval such as `(a,b\}` to denote `Pr[X in (a,b)] + Pr[X = b]/2`.

Do there exist such symbols `\{` `\}` as described? Any alternative?

[image]

Comment: you could draw them with tikz, but readers will probably find them distracting, I'd use [(a,b)] or  ⟨a,b⟩ or ⟬a,b⟭ or ...

Comment: welcome to tex.stack... If you do as per you mentioned, then the readability became very odd....(obviously its my opinion...)

Comment: This is not the probability that the value is in some set. Define a function symbol, say “Pr_h(X;(a,b))” or something like that.